# Hard drive isn't recognized by Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

I have a SATA hard drive that doesn't seem to be properly recognized by Windows. I have plugged it in via an external dock USB dock and Windows recognizes it as ST320005 42AS USB device (it installs the drivers for it), but no drive letter ever shows in My Computer. Do I need to format it somehow? The problem isn't with the USB dock because I have used other hard drives with it. I've had a look in Device Manager and it does show up as a Disk Drive, so why isn't it showing up in My Computer?

It also isn't recognized by Windows if I plug it directly into one of my motherboard's SATA ports (even though the BIOS does see it).

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look in Disk Management? If it's a new drive, it will just need to be initialized and formatted.

Comment: Yup, that was it.

Comment: @Dig A Pony - Glad it was painless.  I was actually surprised that I couldn't find this question having been asked before - I bet this is a common point of confusion!